# Which AWS Service to make videos webready?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-convert

I have users uploading videos in all kinds of formats, some not supported by chrome.

I just want to transcode all videos so they play in the browser, e.g. h.264.

I have looked at AWS Elastic Media Convert that does not have any documentation that is actually explaining how to go from zero to hero, let alone having meaningful templates for jobs.

Is it at all possible to do that with media convert and if not, what would be an appropriate service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes.  Existing AWS Blog articles describe workflows using S3 "watch folders" to convert new files as they arrive, using MediaConvert to covert files to a ubiquitous output format and deliver the converted output to a specified S3 location which can support web access both directly and as an origin for CDN distributions.

There are several considerations (for example: very long input files, exotic file formats, nature of content, etc) for which you may want to account. The design and testing of a multi-step workflow with error handling can be complex. If you wish to use outside expertise, you have at least three options:

[a]  AWS Paid Professional Services  -
There is a large global AWS ProServices team able to help via paid service engagements. The fastest way to start this dialog is by submitting the AWS Sales team 'contact me' form found at this link and specifying 'Sales Support'  :   https://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/

[b]  AWS Certified Consulting Partners  -- The partner search tool & listings are here:  https://iq.aws.amazon.com/services/aws/medialive

[c]  AWS Solutions Architects -- for AWS Enterprise Support customers.  The TAM or the Sales contact linked in item [a] is the best way to engage them. Purchasing AWS Enterprise Support will entitle the customer to a dedicated TAM / SA combination.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/ug/getting-started.html) for AWS Elemental MediaConvert and following the getting started steps will get you a basic understanding of the service.

If there is any specific issue with the usage of the service, please create a new question.

Comment: Yeah, I obviously know this one. It doesn't explain at all how the service works. My question is if I have a video and want to prepare it for browsers, is that even possible.